# Micro SDHC FAT32 address map

Tags: memory

Could anyone please explain where to get the memory address map for micro SDHC FAT32?

I mean, which addresses used for user data, at which addresses to get info about the card itself (Bios Parameter Block), where to define directories etc.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of a FAT32 filesystem is independent of the storage medium. A FAT32 filesystem is laid out the same way no matter whether it's on a SD card, a hard disk, or whatnot.

A specification of the FAT family, including FAT32, is available from Microsoft at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg463080.aspx

This document should cover most of your questions about the filesystem. If you have any specific questions, please ask them separately.